# Sparklyr - Change columns names in a Spark dataframe

Tags: r, apache-spark, rename, sparklyr

```
df <- data.frame(old1 = LETTERS, old2 = 1)
df_tbl <- copy_to(sc,df,"df")

df_tbl <- df_tbl %>% dplyr::rename(old1 = new1, old2 = new2)
```

returns:

```
> head(df_tbl)
Error: `new1`, `new2` contains unknown variables
```

Is there an easy way to change the column names using Sparklyr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you mixed the order:

```
df_tbl %>% rename(new1 = old1, new2 = old2)
```

but with Sparklyr you have to use `select`:

```
df_tbl %>% select(new1 = old1, new2 = old2)
```